# c++ using templates with a singleton

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

would it be possible to use templates with the following singleton class to be able to use the portit function with any datatype not just int? is this a very stupid idea?

```
class porter
{
private:
    static porter* instance;
    porter(){}
    ~porter(){}
public:
    static porter* getInstance()
    {
        if(!instance) 
            instance = new porter();
        return instance;
    }
    void portit(int theArray[])
    {
        //sort array someway
    }
};

porter* porter::instance=NULL;
```

Comment: That depends. Do you want one singleton per templated type?

Comment: Use a singleton -> I've no sympathy.

Comment: @Cameron at this stage i dont mind, ideally there would be one object i could send variables of different types to the same function but if i need seperate singletons thats ok.

Comment: @DeadMG how come you dont like singletons?

Answer (score 2):

A Singleton is bad, but at the very least you could use a simpler implementation:

```
class porter {
public:
    static porter& instance() { static porter P; return P; }

   template <typename T, size_t N>
    void portit(T (&array)[N]) {
        std::sort(array, array + N);
    }

private:
    porter() = default;
    ~porter() = default;
};

// usage
porter::instance().portit(somearray);
```

Of course, using such a singleton just does not make sense. Compare how long it is to write and use with a better implementation:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void sort(T (&array)[N]) { std::sort(array, array + N); }

// usage
sort(somearray);
```

Comment: I think "humming bird" want to parametrize type not size. And there is no hint to use C++11 at all

Comment: @stefanbachert: right sorry, I somehow got it right in the general version but not in the singleton. Patched.

Answer (score 1):

You could use function templates

Something like

```
...
template <typename T>
void portit(T theArray[])
{
    //sort array someway
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So something like...

```
template <typename T>
class porter<T> {
     public:
           template <typename T>
           static porter<T> * getInstance() {

           }
     private:
           static porter<T> * instance;
}
```

??? Note: this might not compile. It's been a while since I've dabbled in templates.

It's definitely possible, but in my opinion you should really think over the design of the whole thing before you start coding, especially if you want to have another template type in the class.

As for whether you want one singleton per class, or one singleton for all instances...well that's a bit more complicated.